# Batch rename files to a sequential numbering

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, rename

I am trying to batch-rename a bunch of files in my shell, and even though there is plenty of material about it on the internet, I cannot seem to find a solution for my specific case.

I have a bunch of files that have (what appears to be) a "timestamp-id":

```
abc_128390.png
abc_138493.png
abc_159084.png
...
```

that I'd like to exchange for a counter:

```
abc_001.png
abc_002.png
abc_003.png
...
```

My (plenty) naïve approach would be something like:

`mv abc_*.png abc_{001..123}.png`

Also, I could not figure out a way to make it work with a `for`-loop.

FWIW, unfortunately `rename` is not available on this particular system.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: FWIW: `abc_*.png abc_{001..123}.png` expands to the existing file names, and then the generated names in sequence, and `mv` has no way to determine what the distinction between them is. (Try e.g. `echo abc_*.png abc_{001..123}.png`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't think of a solution that handles incrementing the counter in a more clever way, but this should work:

```
i=0
for fi in abc_??????.png; do
    mv "$fi" abc_$i.png
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

It should be safe to use `abc_*.png` because it is expanded before the first `mv` is ever executed, but it can be useful to be very specific in that you only want files with a six-character timestamp at the end.

Comment: Change the destination file name to `"$(printf "abc_%03d.png" "$i")"` to get the zero-padding, too

Comment: I had been very close to this solution at one point… The zero-padding is the cherry on top! Thanks1

Comment: Minor point: the line that increments $i can be reduced to just `((i++))`

Answer (score 8):

With `rename` utility as part of Perl packages, you would do:

```
rename -n 'our $i; s/_.*/sprintf("_%03d.png", $i++)/e' *.png
```

*Note: `-n` is for dry run, remove it to rename apply on files.*

Comment: What does the `our $i` mean? I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: @Sruly that's a local variable definition used in the `rename` script.

Comment: after writing the comment here I found that there are a few different rename comments around. Mine is from linux-utils. I'm assuming your answer refers to one of the perl scripts

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh`:

```
typeset -A count
incr='++count[$1/$2]'
(zmv -n '([^0-9]##)<->(*)(#qn)' '$1${(l:3::0:)$((incr))}$2')
```

Remove the `-n` when happy.

(note the extra step using the `incr` variable to [avoid the ACE vulnerability](/q/627474))

Example:

```
$ ls
a1b.png  abc_128390.png  abc_159084.png  x12y.png
a2b.png  abc_138493.png  a.png           x2y.png
$ typeset -A count
$ incr='++count[$1/$2]'
$ (zmv -n '([^0-9]##)<->(*)(#qn)' '$1${(l:3::0:)$((incr))}$2')
mv -- a1b.png a001b.png
mv -- a2b.png a002b.png
mv -- abc_128390.png abc_001.png
mv -- abc_138493.png abc_002.png
mv -- abc_159084.png abc_003.png
mv -- x2y.png x001y.png
mv -- x12y.png x002y.png
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid overwriting existing files:

```
i=1
for fi in abc_??????.png; do
    a="abc_$(printf '%04d' "$i").png"
    if [[ -e $a ]]; then
        echo "file $a exist, not moving $fi"
    else
        mv "$fi" "$a"
    fi
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use cut to cut out parts of the filename, for example, if you want to rename files like

```
"1 first.jpg"
"2 second.jpg"
...
```

to

```
"10 first.jpg"
"20 second.jpg"
...
```

you can use

```
for i in *jpg; do
  mv -iv "$i" "$(echo "$i"|cut -d\  -f1)0 $(echo "$i"|cut -d\  -f2-99)";
done
```

Comment: i like this approach, but I think your delimiter choice is causing the whole filename to be appended. Maybe use the `-c1` and `-c2-99` flags for character instead of field? Prob `-c2-` would capture to end of line.