# Want to rename a files in folder with folder_1.txt folder_2.txt folder_n.txt name

Tags: rename, file-management

I have 3 directories on my Ubuntu machine, named `abc`, `xyz` and `pst`. In each directory, I have approximately 7 files with different names. I want to rename each file like `abc_1.txt`, `abc_2.txt`, `abc_3.txt`, `abc_4.txt`, `abc_5.txt`, `abc_6.txt`, `abc_7.txt`. Similarly, with the `xyz` and `pst` directories.

To clarify, I tried one of the answers below:

```
i=0
for f in */* ; do i=$(( i+1 )) fp=$(dirname "$f"); ext="${f##*.}" ; echo "$f" "$fp"/"$fp"_"$i"."$ext" ;done
```

And the output is:

```
123/1.jpg 123/123_1.jpg
123/2.jpg 123/123_2.jpg
123/3.jpg 123/123_3.jpg
2275/2275_1.jpg 2275/2275_4.jpg
2275/2275_2.jpg 2275/2275_5.jpg
2275/2275_3.jpg 2275/2275_6.jpg
2275/2275_4.jpg 2275/2275_7.jpg
2275/2275_5.jpg 2275/2275_8.jpg
2275/2275_6.jpg 2275/2275_9.jpg
2275/2275_7.jpg 2275/2275_10.jpg
2275/2275_Thumbs.db 2275/2275_11.db
456/1.jpg 456/456_12.jpg
456/2.jpg 456/456_13.jpg
456/3.jpg 456/456_14.jpg
```

But I want the result to be like this:

```
123/1.jpg 123/123_1.jpg
123/2.jpg 123/123_2.jpg
123/3.jpg 123/123_3.jpg
2275/2275_1.jpg 2275/2275_1.jpg
2275/2275_2.jpg 2275/2275_2.jpg
2275/2275_3.jpg 2275/2275_3.jpg
2275/2275_4.jpg 2275/2275_4.jpg
2275/2275_5.jpg 2275/2275_5.jpg
2275/2275_6.jpg 2275/2275_6.jpg
2275/2275_7.jpg 2275/2275_7.jpg
2275/2275_Thumbs.db 2275/2275_8.db
456/1.jpg 456/456_1.jpg
456/2.jpg 456/456_2.jpg
456/3.jpg 456/456_3.jpg
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hello Shubham. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Related: [Rename files with consecutive numbers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497960/100397) and [Batch rename files to a sequential numbering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420927/batch-rename-files-to-a-sequential-numbering).

Comment: Shubham. Please [edit your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/512580/edit) to add information, using the formatting bar as necessary (for example select code and click the `{}` button to format it). Don't put updates in an Answer, and don't put complex replies in comments. Try to make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: @roaima again, this is not a dupe -- the OPs wants the dirname included in the generated filename. while it *may* be possible to adapt the answers from there to [this case](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/512594/308316) (not really sure about it), it's not trivial.

Comment: @roaima I have to agree with Mosvy. While the proposed dupe is certainly relevant and hepful, you need to know your way around the shell to adapt either answer to get the directory's name included. Also, close voters, please try not to close as dupes of questions already closed as dupes. use the final dupe target instead.

Comment: @roaima done! I took the liberty of also adding a link to the duplicate's duplicate. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd /path/to/abc; cnt=0; for i in *.*; do mv "$i" "${PWD##*/}_$((++cnt)).${i##*.}"; done
```

- for each directory abc, xyz, ... you have to `cd` into that directory
- `*.*` used to only select the files with suffix
- replace `mv` with `echo` to see what the result would look like before you mess around

**Edit:**

If you want this for multiple directories and reset the counter in each directory.

Oneliner:

```
for i in */*.*; do [ "$dn" != "${i%/*}" ] && cnt=0; dn="${i%/*}"; mv "$i" "${dn}/${dn}_$((++cnt)).${i##*.}"; done
```

Pretty printed:

```
for i in */*.*; do
    # reset counter if different directory or dn is unset
    [ "$dn" != "${i%/*}" ] && cnt=0

    # set directory name
    dn="${i%/*}"

    # move file
    mv "$i" "${dn}/${dn}_$((++cnt)).${i##*.}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For better understanding please review this:- 
I want to do this in script so i got one command i.e.

```
i=0
for f in */* ; do i=$(( i+1 )) fp=$(dirname "$f"); ext="${f##*.}" ; echo "$f" "$fp"/"$fp"_"$i"."$ext" ;done
```

And the output is like-

```
123/1.jpg 123/123_1.jpg
123/2.jpg 123/123_2.jpg
123/3.jpg 123/123_3.jpg
2275/2275_1.jpg 2275/2275_4.jpg
2275/2275_2.jpg 2275/2275_5.jpg
2275/2275_3.jpg 2275/2275_6.jpg
2275/2275_4.jpg 2275/2275_7.jpg
2275/2275_5.jpg 2275/2275_8.jpg
2275/2275_6.jpg 2275/2275_9.jpg
2275/2275_7.jpg 2275/2275_10.jpg
2275/2275_Thumbs.db 2275/2275_11.db
456/1.jpg 456/456_12.jpg
456/2.jpg 456/456_13.jpg
456/3.jpg 456/456_14.jpg
```

But i want this ouptut is like -

```
123/1.jpg 123/123_1.jpg
123/2.jpg 123/123_2.jpg
123/3.jpg 123/123_3.jpg
2275/2275_1.jpg 2275/2275_1.jpg
2275/2275_2.jpg 2275/2275_2.jpg
2275/2275_3.jpg 2275/2275_3.jpg
2275/2275_4.jpg 2275/2275_4.jpg
2275/2275_5.jpg 2275/2275_5.jpg
2275/2275_6.jpg 2275/2275_6.jpg
2275/2275_7.jpg 2275/2275_7.jpg
2275/2275_Thumbs.db 2275/2275_8.db
456/1.jpg 456/456_1.jpg
456/2.jpg 456/456_2.jpg
456/3.jpg 456/456_3.jpg
```

Comment: try `for d in *; do i=0; for f in "$d/"*; do test -f "$f" || continue; dn=${f%"/${f##*/}"}; echo "$f" "$dn/${dn}_$((i=i+1))${f#"${f%.*}"}"; done; done`