# Re-number and rename

Tags: command-line, rename

I got into a situation that I need to rename lots of files in the form of:

```
file.csv
file_1.csv
file_2.csv
file_3.csv
file_4.csv
file_5.csv
file_6.csv
file_7.csv
file_8.csv
```

To better order, i.e.:

```
file_1.csv
file_2.csv
file_3.csv
file_4.csv
file_5.csv
file_6.csv
file_7.csv
file_8.csv
file_9.csv
```

I.e., I can manually rename the first file, but for the remaining "`_#`" files, I need to renumber them with `+1`. I tried to use

```
rename -n -v 's/_(.*)./.(\1+1)./'
```

but got

```
file_(1+1).csv
file_(2+1).csv
```

etc.

Any easy way to batch remain the "`_#`" files please?

PS, better as

```
file_01.csv
. . .
file_09.csv
file_10.csv
. . .
```

if possible.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to cas' answer. Because I'll rename them as zero-padded names, so there won't be conflict in file names, so to me the command can be simplified as:

```bsh
touch file.csv file_{1..9}.csv

$ rename -v 's/^(file_)(\d+)(\.csv)$/$1 . (sprintf "%02i", $2 + 1) . $3/e' file_*
file_1.csv renamed as file_02.csv
file_2.csv renamed as file_03.csv
file_3.csv renamed as file_04.csv
file_4.csv renamed as file_05.csv
file_5.csv renamed as file_06.csv
file_6.csv renamed as file_07.csv
file_7.csv renamed as file_08.csv
file_8.csv renamed as file_09.csv
file_9.csv renamed as file_10.csv
```

Note the last two file names:

```
file_09.csv
file_10.csv
```

Comment: You could not have got the output you show you got based on the command you ran. The greedy regex .* Would have swallowed upto .cs and leaving only v.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/497960/100397 for a way to do this using `rename`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use perl's `/e` regex modifier to cause it to evaluate the right-hand-side of the `s///` operation as a perl expression.

You also need to sort the filenames in **reverse** numerical order so that the highest-numbered filenames are renamed **before** the lower-numbered filenames (otherwise there will be filename collisions - by default, unless you use `-f` to force it, `rename` will refuse to overwrite existing files).  To do this, I'll use GNU `find` with `-print0` and GNU `sort` with `-z` for NUL-terminated input, `-r` and `-V` for a reverse version (i.e. "natural") sort.  `-t _` and `-k 2` options are also used to sort from the second field.

rename's `-d` option is used to make it rename the filename portion of a pathname only, and `-0` to make it take a NUL-separated list of files on stdin.

e.g.

```
$ touch file.csv file_{1..8}.csv
$ find . -name 'file_*.csv' -print0 |
    sort -z -t _ -k2 -r -V |
    rename -d -0 's/^(file_)(\d+)(\.csv)$/$1 . ($2 + 1) . $3/e'
$ mv file.csv file_1.csv
$ ls -l
total 5
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_1.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_2.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_3.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_4.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_5.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_6.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_7.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_8.csv
-rw-r--r-- 1 cas cas 0 Aug 21 15:22 file_9.csv
```

This could be simplified a little, but I've made the regex explicitly look for and capture `file_`, one-or-more digits, and the `.csv` extension to avoid any possibility of renaming files it shouldn't.

To make the file numbering zero-padded, you can use the `sprintf` function.  e.g.

```
... | rename -0 -d -v 's/^(file_)(\d+)(\.csv)$/$1 . (sprintf "%02i", $2 + 1) . $3/e'
Reading filenames from file handle (GLOB(0x555555905960))
./file_8.csv renamed as ./file_09.csv
./file_7.csv renamed as ./file_08.csv
./file_6.csv renamed as ./file_07.csv
./file_5.csv renamed as ./file_06.csv
./file_4.csv renamed as ./file_05.csv
./file_3.csv renamed as ./file_04.csv
./file_2.csv renamed as ./file_03.csv
./file_1.csv renamed as ./file_02.csv
```

Comment: Bravo!!! And thanks for answering the bonus _"zero-padded"_ question as well!!

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
$ autoload -Uz zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
$ LC_ALL=C zmv -f -n '(file)(|_(<->))(.csv)(#qnOn)' '${1}_$(($3+1))$4'
mv -- file_11.csv file_12.csv
mv -- file_10.csv file_11.csv
mv -- file_9.csv file_10.csv
mv -- file_8.csv file_9.csv
mv -- file_7.csv file_8.csv
mv -- file_6.csv file_7.csv
mv -- file_5.csv file_6.csv
mv -- file_4.csv file_5.csv
mv -- file_3.csv file_4.csv
mv -- file_2.csv file_3.csv
mv -- file_1.csv file_2.csv
mv -- file.csv file_1.csv
```

Or with the `0`-padding using the `${(l[2][0])...}` left-padding parameter expansion flag:

```
$ LC_ALL=C zmv -fn '(file)(|_(<->))(.csv)(#qnOn)' '${1}_${(l[2][0])$(($3+1))}$4'
mv -- file_11.csv file_12.csv
mv -- file_10.csv file_11.csv
mv -- file_9.csv file_10.csv
mv -- file_8.csv file_09.csv
mv -- file_7.csv file_08.csv
mv -- file_6.csv file_07.csv
mv -- file_5.csv file_06.csv
mv -- file_4.csv file_05.csv
mv -- file_3.csv file_04.csv
mv -- file_2.csv file_03.csv
mv -- file_1.csv file_02.csv
mv -- file.csv file_01.csv
```

(remove the `-n` (dry-run) if OK).

That renames files that are generated by that `extendedglob` glob where:

- `<->` matches any sequence of digits (it's the `<x-y>` decimal integer number matching operators with no bound specified)
- `(#q...)` specifies glob qualifiers where:

  - `n`: toggles numericglobsort
  - `On`: sorts in reverse by name. So `file8` comes before `file7` but also thanks to numericglobsort above, `file10` comes before `file9`. The `LC_ALL=C` is to make sure the `_` and `.` are not ignored in the sorting algorithm so `file.csv` comes after `file_1.csv`

In the replacement, `$1`, `$2`... contain what is matched by each respective pair of `(`, `)` in the pattern like in `perl`'s `s///` operator.

The `-f` is there to disable `zmv`'s sanity checks which would complain for instance that `file6.csv` would be renamed to an already existing `file7.csv` (even though by that time, `file7.csv` would have already been renamed to `file8.csv`).

You could use perl's `rename` to do the renaming but you'd still need something like `zsh` globs to pass the list in the right order:

```
$ (LC_ALL=C; rename -f -n '
    s{^(file)(?:_(\d*))?(\.csv)\Z}{
      "${1}_" . (($2 // 0) + 1) . $3}se
   ' file(|_<->).csv(nOn))
rename(file_11.csv, file_12.csv)
rename(file_10.csv, file_11.csv)
rename(file_9.csv, file_10.csv)
rename(file_7.csv, file_8.csv)
rename(file_6.csv, file_7.csv)
rename(file_5.csv, file_6.csv)
rename(file_4.csv, file_5.csv)
rename(file_3.csv, file_4.csv)
rename(file_2.csv, file_3.csv)
rename(file_1.csv, file_2.csv)
rename(file.csv, file_1.csv)
```

Replace `(($2 // 0) + 1)` with `sprintf("%02d", ($2 // 0) + 1)` for instance to do the 0-padding.

If you don't have and can't install `zsh`, but you're on a GNU system, you can get those files in the right order with `bash` as:

```
eval "files=(
  $(
    shopt -s extglob failglob
    export LC_ALL=C
    ls --quoting-style=shell-always -rvd file?(_+([0-9])).csv
   )
)"
```

Relying on GNU `ls -rv` to list the files in reverse version order.

And then call `rename ... "${files[@]}"` with the same `rename` code as above to do the renaming.

Here, as the names of the files are very simple and assuming there's no other file that matches `file*.csv`, and with the default value of `$IFS`, you could also do (still with GNU ls but with any Bourne-like shell):

```
rename ... $(LC_ALL=C ls -rvd file*.csv)
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do that can be as shown:

```
set -- file_*.csv

while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
  set -- "$#" "$@"
  mv -- "file_$1.csv" "file_$#.csv"
  shift 2
done

mv file.csv file_1.csv
```

If you wanted left zero padded filenames you change the `mv` statements to:

```
mv -- "file_$1.csv" "$(printf 'file_%02d.csv\n' "$#")"
mv file.csv file_01.csv
```

If it is a concern that your command line arguments are getting destroyed then you can take all this action inside a function and call that function.