# Add file number to beginning of each file in directory

Tags: bash, files, filenames

If I have a directory, how do I add the number of the file to beginning of the filename? For example, the directory would look something like this:

```
file.txt
another_file.txt
```

And the expected output would be:

```
1_file.txt
2_another_file.txt
```

Is there a way to do this? I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787413/rename-files-and-directories-add-prefix), but I amn't sure how to change the prefix for each file (in this example, have it increase by one each time).

Comment: Related: [Batch rename files to a sequential numbering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420927/batch-rename-files-to-a-sequential-numbering)

Comment: `ls | nl ...` => see `man nl`