# How to modify this `while read; mv printf` code to rename only files of certain filetype?

Tags: bash, shell-script, ls, rename, printf

Code in question:

```
ls | cat -n | while read n f; do mv "$f" `printf "video_%03d.mp4" $n`; done
```

The above code will rename all files/folders within the directory executed to:

```
video_001.mp4
video_002.mp4
video_003.mp4
and so on...
```

However, it would be nice to only target files of specific type, such as only renaming the `.mp4` files, rather than renaming everything, which includes directories.

Comment: See also [Batch rename files to a sequential numbering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420927/batch-rename-files-to-a-sequential-numbering)

Comment: See also [Batch renaming files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1136/batch-renaming-files/114587#114587)

Comment: For more U&L information on "globs" or "wildcards", see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildcards

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This renames all `.mp4` files, without parsing `ls`:

```
i=1; for file in *.mp4; do mv "$file" $(printf "video_%03d.mp4" "$i"); i=$((i + 1)); done
```

Any glob can be used in the `for file in ...` statement. You could apply other criteria by using `find` instead.