# Batch rename to same name but indexed

Tags: rename

Having files

```
foo.png bar.png baz.png
```

How to rename all of them to the same file name differentiated with an index number?

```
qux1.png qux2.png qux3.png
```

Ideally, I am looking for a command that can accept a substitute expression like `s/.*\.png/qux<???>.png/` where `<???>` is the part I am not able to figure out.

Comment: Does this help? [Batch rename files to a sequential numbering](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420927/batch-rename-files-to-a-sequential-numbering)

Comment: Thank you, yes, this answer was what I was looking for: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421036/472602